# Recreating past landscapes on ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, visualisation, landscape

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

I am trying to recreate the landscape as it may have been around 4000 BC. I have an idea about what tree species existed in particular regions of Scotland (by reading pollen studies). Now I need to somehow add trees to the Land-Form PANORAMA raster (taken from Ordnance survey UK) to visualize the landscape. I am aware of adding layers (with different datasets - for instance geological information) but I am not sure how I can add tree cover in ArcMap as I don't have this information in the form of a layer which can be added to the raster.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looking at your other Q&As, I suspect that you will now know how to do what you asked about last year.  If not, would you be able to edit your Question to provide more details, please?  It sounds like you just need to create a new feature class, and digitize into it using an image as background.  Or are you wanting to symbolize tree points and then "burn" them into your raster?